# Display ListView in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Not able to display the list in fragment.. 
Error:

```
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 9058
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqltest/com.example.jobtracker.ReadComments}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
11-05 11:57:32.987: E/AndroidRuntime(9058):     ... 11 more
```

this is `fragment_Jobqueue.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:text="Job Queue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewjobqueue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
        android:divider="#0000CC">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`displayList.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip" 
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`JobQueueFragment.java`

```
    public class JobqueueFragment extends ListFragment {

    public JobqueueFragment(){}

    private static final String JOBQUEUE_URL = "http://192.168.2.102/webservice/jobqueue.php";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONArray jsonParser = null;

    private ListView mainListView;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "msg";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "message";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "ClientName";
    private static final String TAG_QUANTITY = "Quantity";


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ctx = inflater.getContext();//.getApplicationContext();
        mainListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById( R.id.listViewjobqueue);
        new JobQueue().execute();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobqueue, container, false);
    }

    class JobQueue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr1 = sh.makeServiceCall(JOBQUEUE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            String[] separated = jsonStr1.split("#4");

            String jsonStr = separated[1].replace('"', '\"');

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    jsonParser = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonParser.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonParser.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        StringBuffer qty = new StringBuffer(c.getString(TAG_QUANTITY));
                        String quantity = new String(qty.append(" images"));

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ctx, contactList,
                                R.layout.displaylist, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_QUANTITY
                        }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.quantity});

                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use this  fragment_Jobqueue.xml: 
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
    android:divider="#0000CC">

</ListView>
```

bro attach this code into on resume

```
JobQueueFragment.java


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobqueue, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    ctx = getActivity();
    mainListView = getListView();
    new JobQueue().execute();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I just started with android ... i did the changes still getting error ... can i attach the code some where to u...

Comment: please post your exceptions

Comment: 11-05 12:41:36.115: W/dalvikvm(20002): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41639d88) 11-05 12:41:36.115: W/ResourceType(20002): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes 11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 20002 11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)

Comment: amitkumar.gajraula@gmail.com

Comment: 11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 30210
11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-05 16:57:57.775: E/AndroidRuntime(30210):  at java.uti

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
public class JobqueueFragment extends Fragment {

    public JobqueueFragment(){
    }

    private static final String JOBQUEUE_URL = "http://192.168.2.102/webservice/jobqueue.php";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONArray jsonParser = null;

    private ListView mainListView;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "succes public class JobqueueFragment extends ListFragment {

    public JobqueueFragment(){}

    private static final String JOBQUEUE_URL = "http://192.168.2.102/webservice/jobqueue.php";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONArray jsonParser = null;

    private ListView mainListView;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "msg";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "message";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "ClientName";
    private static final String TAG_QUANTITY = "Quantity";


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ctx = inflater.getContext();//.getApplicationContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobqueue, container, false)
        mainListView = (ListView) view.findViewById( R.id.listViewjobqueue);
        new JobQueue().execute();

        return view;
    }

    class JobQueue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr1 = sh.makeServiceCall(JOBQUEUE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            String[] separated = jsonStr1.split("#4");

            String jsonStr = separated[1].replace('"', '\"');

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    jsonParser = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonParser.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonParser.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        StringBuffer qty = new StringBuffer(c.getString(TAG_QUANTITY));
                        String quantity = new String(qty.append(" images"));

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ctx, contactList,
                                R.layout.displaylist, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_QUANTITY
                        }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.quantity});

                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i change it fragment then setListAdapter will give error saying

Comment: method undefined to this fragment

Comment: change it by mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: 11-05 12:41:36.115: W/dalvikvm(20002): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41639d88)
11-05 12:41:36.115: W/ResourceType(20002): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 20002
11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-05 12:41:36.125: E/AndroidRuntime(20002):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)


Still Error

Comment: ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ctx, contactList,
                                R.layout.displaylist, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_QUANTITY
                        }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.quantity});

                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Pass me ur mail id.. i will send the code to u.. plz help me out stuck in it from yesterday...

Comment: akash@tasolglobal.com